# R: Calculate the mean and variance of length N elements in a vector

Tags: r, statistics

I'm new to R.

I'm trying to calculate the mean and variance of a vector.

However rather than simply calculating the mean and variance of the *whole* vector, I am trying to calculate the mean and variance of each "block of 10 elements".

For example

```
v <- c(1:100)
mean(v) # returns 50.5
var(v) # returns 841.6667
```

what I actually want is a new vector, with length 10, containing this:

```
mean(v[1:10]), mean(v[11:20]), ... , mean(v[91:100])
```

(and also the variance)

```
var(v[1:10]), var(v[11:20]), ... , var(v[91:100])
```

However I don't know how to accomplish this in a sensible way. Any help appreciated even if that is "go read this reference at [url]". I tried duckduckgo searching for this, but to no avail.

Seems like something that should be easy?

Comment: Several alternatives here: [Calculate the mean of every 13 rows in data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30359427/calculate-the-mean-of-every-13-rows-in-data-frame). Replace the `nrow` (of the data frame) with `length` (of your vector)

Answer (score 1):

Create a grouping variable that increments 1 every 10 values

```
grp <- as.integer(gl(length(v), 10, length(v)))
```

and then use a group by operation

```
tapply(v, grp, mean)
tapply(v, grp, var)
```

---

Or this can be done in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
tibble(v) %>%
    group_by(grp = as.integer(gl(n(), 10, n()))) %>%
    summarise(Mean = mean(v), Var = var(v), .groups = 'drop')
```

Comment: Ok, I'm going to have to check out group variables and tapply as I've not seen these before, give me a few mins to do some searching