# Finding the Median for every 3 values in a column

Tags: r, median

I would like a line of code that is capable of finding the median of every 3 column values in the Fin1 column. E.g First value would be 5.08 out of 1.54, 5.08 and 5.26. The second would be 5.27 out of 2.79, 5.27 and 8.12. The whole data set contains 36 rows so this operation would have to occur 12 times.

(See data frame below)

```
Block trial Trial Category   Fin1    Fin2    Fin3   Fin4    Correct FastFin

2      1     2     1      1 1.5424  0.00000 0.00000 0.0000       1  1.5424

7      1     7     3      1 5.2617  0.97171 2.41070 3.8407       1  5.2617

9      1     9     2      1 5.0827  0.00000 0.00000 1.1977       1  5.0827

16     2    16     1      1 5.2732  1.28220 0.00000 3.0692       1  5.2732

19     2    19     2      1 8.1251  6.98210 1.52210 0.0000       1  8.1251

24     2    24     3      1 2.7960  1.87000 0.52903 0.0000       1  2.7960
```

Comment: Very slight modification of most of the answers from [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30359427/calculate-the-mean-of-every-13-rows-in-data-frame) work. For instance, from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30359736/12109788), just change it to `aggregate(df$Fin1, list(rep(seq_len(nrow(df) %/% n + 1), each = n, len = nrow(df))), median)[-1]` and `n <- 3`

Comment: Also, you may want to consider *why* you are getting central tendency for every three rows - if they are all linked in some way (ie, every three rows is the same patient, or location), you could create a group variable and use: `df$grp <- rep(seq_len(nrow(df) / n), each = 3); tapply(df$AFin1, df$grp, median)`

Comment: using `dplyr` you can use `df %>% group_by(trial) %>% summarise(med = median(Fin1))`

Comment: This is a sub-case of "summarize by group", see https://stackoverflow.com/q/11562656/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/12064202/3358272 (multiple functions). The new component is "how to group by three rows".

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is figuring out how to "group" every three consecutive rows. Once we have that, this then becomes a simple aggregate by group.

I'll use a `grp` variable to do that, calculating with `cumsum((rownum - 1) %% 3 == 0)`

#### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
quux %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum((row_number() - 1) %% 3 == 0)) %>%
  mutate(val = median(Fin1)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 6 × 12
#   Block trial Trial Category  Fin1  Fin2  Fin3  Fin4 Correct FastFin   grp   val
#   <int> <int> <int>    <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <int>   <dbl> <int> <dbl>
# 1     1     2     1        1  1.54 0     0      0          1    1.54     1  5.08
# 2     1     7     3        1  5.26 0.972 2.41   3.84       1    5.26     1  5.08
# 3     1     9     2        1  5.08 0     0      1.20       1    5.08     1  5.08
# 4     2    16     1        1  5.27 1.28  0      3.07       1    5.27     2  5.27
# 5     2    19     2        1  8.13 6.98  1.52   0          1    8.13     2  5.27
# 6     2    24     3        1  2.80 1.87  0.529  0          1    2.80     2  5.27
```

If you needed all `Fin#` columns, then

```r
quux %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum((row_number() - 1) %% 3 == 0)) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("Fin"), ~ median(.x), .names = "{.col}_median")) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 6 × 15
#   Block trial Trial Category  Fin1  Fin2  Fin3  Fin4 Correct FastFin   grp Fin1_median Fin2_median Fin3_median Fin4_median
#   <int> <int> <int>    <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <int>   <dbl> <int>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1     1     2     1        1  1.54 0     0      0          1    1.54     1        5.08        0          0            1.20
# 2     1     7     3        1  5.26 0.972 2.41   3.84       1    5.26     1        5.08        0          0            1.20
# 3     1     9     2        1  5.08 0     0      1.20       1    5.08     1        5.08        0          0            1.20
# 4     2    16     1        1  5.27 1.28  0      3.07       1    5.27     2        5.27        1.87       0.529        0   
# 5     2    19     2        1  8.13 6.98  1.52   0          1    8.13     2        5.27        1.87       0.529        0   
# 6     2    24     3        1  2.80 1.87  0.529  0          1    2.80     2        5.27        1.87       0.529        0
```

#### base R

```r
grp <- cumsum((0:(nrow(quux)-1) %% 3) == 0)
grp
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2
Fins <- startsWith(names(quux), "Fin")
newFins <- paste0(Fins, "_median")
Fins
# [1] "Fin1" "Fin2" "Fin3" "Fin4"
newFins
# [1] "Fin1_median" "Fin2_median" "Fin3_median" "Fin4_median"
quux[,newFins] <- lapply(setNames(quux[,Fins], paste0(Fins, "_median")), function(val) ave(val, grp, FUN = median))
quux
#    Block trial Trial Category   Fin1    Fin2    Fin3   Fin4 Correct FastFin Fin1_median Fin2_median Fin3_median Fin4_median
# 2      1     2     1        1 1.5424 0.00000 0.00000 0.0000       1  1.5424      5.0827        0.00     0.00000      1.1977
# 7      1     7     3        1 5.2617 0.97171 2.41070 3.8407       1  5.2617      5.0827        0.00     0.00000      1.1977
# 9      1     9     2        1 5.0827 0.00000 0.00000 1.1977       1  5.0827      5.0827        0.00     0.00000      1.1977
# 16     2    16     1        1 5.2732 1.28220 0.00000 3.0692       1  5.2732      5.2732        1.87     0.52903      0.0000
# 19     2    19     2        1 8.1251 6.98210 1.52210 0.0000       1  8.1251      5.2732        1.87     0.52903      0.0000
# 24     2    24     3        1 2.7960 1.87000 0.52903 0.0000       1  2.7960      5.2732        1.87     0.52903      0.0000
```

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(Block = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), trial = c(2L, 7L, 9L, 16L, 19L, 24L), Trial = c(1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L), Category = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Fin1 = c(1.5424, 5.2617, 5.0827, 5.2732, 8.1251, 2.796), Fin2 = c(0, 0.97171, 0, 1.2822, 6.9821, 1.87), Fin3 = c(0, 2.4107, 0, 0, 1.5221, 0.52903), Fin4 = c(0, 3.8407, 1.1977, 3.0692, 0, 0), Correct = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), FastFin = c(1.5424, 5.2617, 5.0827, 5.2732, 8.1251, 2.796)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("2", "7", "9",  "16", "19", "24"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating a `matrix` with 3 rows then using `matrixStats::colMedians`.

```
> matrixStats::colMedians(matrix(quux$Fin1, nrow=3))
[1] 5.0827 5.2732
```

Data borrowed from *r2evans*.